Vercel - Frontend not communicating with Backend correctly
I am trying to deploy a full-stack project with a React frontend and an Express.js backend using Vercel. While everything works fine locally, I am encountering issues after deployment. Specifically, my backend routes are returning 404 Not Found errors. I am using the Unsplash API to fetch random photos and display it as a static background image for my React app.
/backend
  ├── index.js
  ├── package-lock.json
  ├── package.json
  ├── .env
  └── Unsplash
      └── unsplash.js
/frontend
  ├── build
  ├── src
  ├── public
  ├── package.json
  └── ...
.gitignore
Makefile
vercel.json


index.js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

const { getRandomImage } = require('./Unsplash/unsplash');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5001;

const corsOptions = {
  origin: [
    'https://bryan-website-red.vercel.app',
  ],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};


app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Test route
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Backend is running!');
});

app.get('/random-image', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const imageData = await getRandomImage();
    console.log('Image data fetched successfully:', imageData); // Add logging
    res.json(imageData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching Unsplash image:', error); // Add logging
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

unsplash.js
const axios = require('axios');

async function getRandomImage() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Client-ID ${process.env.UNSPLASH_ACCESS_KEY}`,
      },
    });

    const downloadLocation = response.data.links.download_location;

    // Trigger the download endpoint
    await axios.get(downloadLocation, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Client-ID ${process.env.UNSPLASH_ACCESS_KEY}`,
      },
    });

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching Unsplash image:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch image from Unsplash');
  }
}

module.exports = {
  getRandomImage
};

vercel.json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "backend/index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    },
    {
      "src": "frontend/package.json",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "distDir": "build"
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "dest": "/backend/index.js"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/frontend/$1"
    }
  ]
}

After deploying, accessing https://bryan-website-red.vercel.app/test returns a 404 Not Found error. Similarly, other backend routes are also not accessible.
My Vercel dashboard doesn't seem to be throwing any errors regarding my backend.Vercel dashboard
I also tried running https://bryan-website-red.vercel.app/test on Postman and it returned a:
The page could not be found
NOT_FOUND
Steps Taken

Verified the environment variables are set correctly in the Vercel dashboard.
Checked the Vercel deployment logs for errors or warnings (none found).
Ensured the vercel.json routes correctly pointed to the back and frontend.
Added a simple test route in the backend to verify its accessibility.

Despite these steps, the backend routes are still not found. Is there something I am missing in my configuration? Has anyone successfully deployed a similar full-stack application on Vercel and can provide insights?
